# apex pagination - Fetch all rows

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an IG in my app which returns 138 rows and most of my users are used to “CTRL+F” to find something on the page and they are not able to find the result, as only 40 rows are fetched at a time. I know this is a natural drawback of any kind of pagination. Any suggestions on how to increase the number of rows fetched on page load?

Answer (score 3):

Tell most of your users to use Apex' search capabilities:

[image]

---

Alternatively, modify number of rows displayed per page; as there are 138 rows, set it to 1000 (don't forget to **save** the report, then!). Though, what will you do if report contains more than 1000 rows? I'd do what I suggested first: **search** using the "Search" bar.

[image]

Comment: Actually my total row count is 160. I tried increaing the rows per page to 1000 but the page loading has increased. I know its expected. Can I declare this rows per page globally for all the pages?